# How can I advance time when testing on Rinkeby network?

Tags: testnets, openzeppelin, rinkeby, time

I've successfully deployed my contract to Rinkeby. Testing on Remix everything worked fine. I'm now writing some tests in Javascript but I don't know how to advance time to test functions in a contract already deployed on Rinkeby. Using the openzeppelin testhelper {time} did not work. Is there a way to advance time in my tests or is that only possible on a Rinkeby fork using ganache-cli?

```
//--------------------configuring web3 for rinkeby---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');

// Read in mnemonic from file
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const secretPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '.secret');
const mnemonic = fs.readFileSync(secretPath, 'utf8').toString().trim();


const Web3 = require("web3");

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws/v3/${infuraID}` )

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

//------------------- requiring some testing Libraries---------------------------------------------------------------------------
require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers/configure')({
  provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws/v3/${infuraID}`),
});


const { expectRevert, time } = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');
const assert = require('assert');


const compiledContractJson = require('../build/contracts/Tradingbot.json');

process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=10;


let accounts;
let contractInstance;

instance before each it-statement
beforeEach(async () => {
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  const deploymentKey = Object.keys(compiledContractJson.networks)[0];

  contractInstance = await new web3.eth.Contract(compiledContractJson.abi, compiledContractJson.networks[deploymentKey].address);
});


describe('Testing Tradingbot_v2', () => {
  it('Contract available on Rinkeby', () => {
    console.log(contractInstance.options.address);
    console.log(accounts);

    assert.ok(contractInstance.options.address);
  });

  it('Buys an initial asset if pool exists', async () => {

    await contractInstance.methods._reset().send({
      from: accounts[0]
    });

    await contractInstance.methods.initialize(100, 90).send({
      from: accounts[0]
    });


    const min = await contractInstance.methods.minAmount().call();
    console.log("Minimum Amount: ", min);
    assert.equal(100, min);

    await contractInstance.methods.contribute().send({
      from: accounts[0],
      value: '1000'
    });

    let balance = await contractInstance.methods.getTokenBalance('0x5592EC0cfb4dbc12D3aB100b257153436a1f0FEa').call();
    balance = parseFloat(balance);
    console.log("Balance after first contribution: ", balance);
    assert(balance > 0);

    await contractInstance.methods.contribute().send({
      from: accounts[1],
      value: '1000'
    });

    const oldBalance = balance;
    balance = await contractInstance.methods.getTokenBalance('0x5592EC0cfb4dbc12D3aB100b257153436a1f0FEa').call();
    console.log("Balance after second contribution: ", balance);
    assert(balance > oldBalance);

    console.log("Timestamp before: ", await time.latest());
    await time.increase(time.duration.seconds(50));
    console.log("Timestamp after: ", await time.latest());

    const investAmount = parseInt(balance * 0.5);
    await contractInstance.methods.initialAssetBuy('0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984', investAmount).send({from: accounts[0]});
    balance = await contractInstance.methods.getTokenBalance('0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984').call();
    console.log("Balance of UNI: ", balance);


  });
```

This is the error I recieve:

```
 1 passing (58s)
  1 failing

  1) Testing Tradingbot_v2
       Buys an initial asset if pool exists:
     Error: Provider does not have a request or send method to use.
      at RequestManager.send (node_modules\web3-core-requestmanager\lib\index.js:164:15)
      at sendRequest (node_modules\web3-core-method\lib\index.js:623:42)
      at Eth.send [as getBlock] (node_modules\web3-core-method\lib\index.js:655:13)
      at Object.latest (node_modules\@openzeppelin\test-helpers\src\time.js:36:32)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\Tradingbot.test.js:216:50)
      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)



warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in build/contracts/IWETH9.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
User (main *) cryptotradingbot_v1
$
```

Comment: Rinkeby is a public blockchain you can't advance the time. If you were using ganache or forking rinkeby into a test blockchain you will be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Ismael for the clarification on Rinkeby. I just was not sure if there were any features available on the testnet. I finally solved my problem by using the following function in my node.js testfile to pause the code execution.

function sleep(ms) {
return new Promise((resolve) => {
setTimeout(resolve, ms);
});
}